# How can I get an apex:repeat in a radio group to render in a single column in a Visualforce page using SLDS?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I have a Salesforce Visualforce page built with the Lightning Design System that incorporates an  value as a radio group. The radio group is, for some reason, being displayed in a single row:

[image: Visualforce Page Screenshot]

I'd like the radio group to display in a single column. I thought this was the default behavior for radio groups in Lightning Design System - is there something in my code that's overriding that functionality and putting all the radio buttons in a single row?

Here's the current code I have for the radio button group:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <label class="slds-radio">
                      <input type="radio" name="options" id="Group" onclick="showHideIndividualAndGroup();"/> 
                      <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
                        <span class="slds-page-header__title">Group (Please click here and select your group from the list.) If you did not sign up with a group, please select Individual.</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div id="pbControl">


                    <div id="divGroup" style="display:none" class="slds-page-header__title">                        
                        <apex:outputPanel id="opnGroup">
                            <apex:outputText value="Groups:"></apex:outputText><br/>

                            <apex:repeat value="{!mapGroup}" var="group" id="rptGroup">

                                <label class="slds-radio">
                                  <span class="slds-radio--faux"><input type="radio" name="options" onclick="passId('{!mapGroup[group].GW_Volunteers__Contact__c}')"/>
                                  </span>
                                    <span class="slds-page-header__title">
                                        {!IF(mapGroup[group].GW_Volunteers__Contact__r.GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Organization__c != null, mapGroup[group].GW_Volunteers__Contact__r.GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Organization__c, mapGroup[group].GW_Volunteers__Contact__r.Name)}
                                    </span>
                                    </label>
                                        </apex:repeat><br/>
                            <div>
                                <span>Did you sign up through a youth group?</span>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:10px;">
                                    <apex:selectList id="GroupPicklist" value="{!byPassWaiverPage}" size="1">
                                        <apex:selectoption itemLabel="No" itemValue="No"></apex:selectoption>
                                        <apex:selectoption itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes"></apex:selectoption>

                                        <!--<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!redirectWaiverPage}"></apex:actionSupport>-->
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </div><br/>
```

EDIT: Source Code for the element on the page:

```
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <label class="slds-radio">
                      <input id="Group" name="options" onclick="showHideIndividualAndGroup();" type="radio" /> 
                      <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
                        <span class="slds-page-header__title">Group (Please click here and select your group from the list.)</span><div class="slds-page-header__title">If you did not sign up with a group, please select Individual.</div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div id="pbControl">
                    <div class="slds-page-header__title" id="divGroup" style="display:none"><span id="j_id0:frm:opnGroup">Groups:<br /><br />
                            <div>
                                <span>Did you sign up through a youth group?</span>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; margin-left:10px;"><select id="j_id0:frm:GroupPicklist" name="j_id0:frm:GroupPicklist" size="1">  <option value="No">No</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
                                </div>
                            </div></span>
                    </div>
                </div><br />
```

Comment: Strange, your screenshot doesn't look like SLDS at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an additional break `<br/>` before the end of the `<apex:repeat>`

```
<apex:repeat value="{!mapGroup}" var="group" id="rptGroup">
.........
<br/>
</apex:repeat>
```